# R - Reduce() not working with median

Tags: r

I've been doing:

```
mylist<- c(2,5,19,29)
Reduce("+", mylist)
```

Result:

```
[1] 55
```

without any problem. However, then I needed to do a median, so I did:

```
Reduce(median, mylist)
```

which give me:

```
[1] 2
```

but the answer is supposed to be:

```
median(unlist(hom))
[1] 12
```

Can someone explain why `Reduce()` is doing this?

Comment: Why not just do `median(myList)`? `Reduce` is intended for binary operators.

Comment: Also `Reduce("+", mylist)` could be done using `sum` much faster.

Comment: ...in fact, I'm not even sure that `Reduce` _could_ correctly calculate the median, since it would be calculating successive medians between pairs of values, which seems sure to give you the wrong answer.

Comment: @joran - it should give the same thing as calculating

Comment: FYI : `Reduce(median,sort(mylist,decreasing=TRUE)) != Reduce(median,mylist)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Reduce` needs a binary operation. `median` is not. What you are computing with `Reduce` is basically something like `median(2, median(5, median(19, 29)))` which is `2` because the second argument to `median` is interpreted as `median`'s second  argument 'na.rm'.

```
Reduce(median, mylist) = median(2, median(5,median(19,29)))
= median(2, median(5,19))
= median(2, 5)
= 2
```